# Excel userform: how to check certain cells before accepting data?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

```
Private Sub CancelCommandButton_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub ClearCommandButton_Click()
    Call UserForm_Initialize
End Sub

Private Sub OkCommandButton_Click()
    Dim emptyRow As Long

    Sheet1.Activate

    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

    Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = EntityNameTextBox.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = JurComboBox.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = MailTypeComboBox.Value
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    EntityNameTextBox.Value = ""

    JurComboBox.Clear

    With JurComboBox
        .AddItem "AL"
        .AddItem "AK"
        .AddItem "AR"
        .AddItem "AZ"
        .AddItem "CA"
        .AddItem "CO"
        .AddItem "CT"
        .AddItem "DE"
        .AddItem "HI"
        .AddItem "IA"
    End With

    MailTypeComboBox.Clear

    With MailTypeComboBox
        .AddItem "AR"
        .AddItem "ARR"
        .AddItem "DOR"
        .AddItem "DTN"
        .AddItem "FAR"
    End With

    EntityNameTextBox.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you missed the 'context', 'question', and 'expected results' part of your post.

Comment: I basically need to to make sure the data entered in the text box is not the same as the data in certain cells. I need it to show an error message. I am pretty new to this so I would really appreciate some help so I can learn :)

Comment: `If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns("A"), EntityNameTextBox.Value) > 0 Then MsgBox EntityNameTextBox.Value & " already exists." Else ...`

Comment: Please read [mcve] and [ask]. As it stands, this post isn't a question.

Comment: Can this be applies to strings?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code:

```
Private Sub OkCommandButton_Click()
    Dim emptyRow As Long
    Dim MsgString as String

    Sheet1.Activate

    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

    MsgString = "Do you want to update data?" & vbNewLine & "A" & emptyRow & " = " & EntityNameTextBox.Value & vbNewLine & "B" & emptyRow & " = " & JurComboBox.Value & vbNewLine & "C" & emptyRow & " = " & MailTypeComboBox.Value
    If MsgBox(MsgString, vbYesNo, "Update confirmation...!!!") = vbYes Then
        Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = EntityNameTextBox.Value
        Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = JurComboBox.Value
        Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = MailTypeComboBox.Value
    Else
        Msgbox "Data Update failed.", vbExclamation, "Failed update data."
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you! Where can I put what cells and from which worksheet?

Comment: Your code is Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value. A is for column 1, B for column 2 and so on.

Comment: Sorry, you can put it in MsgString.

Comment: I think I worded that wrong. I know what cells the data will be put into. I just need a msgbox to come up when someone enters any data from A2:A5 on worksheet 2

Comment: what are criteria which need a msgbox come up?